# How can I add values per unique string?

Tags: bash, awk

Basically, I extract a string and an integer from a text file with:

```
cat file.txt | cut -d " " -f 1,3 | sort
```

The output looks like this:

```
white 3
white 2
white 54
red 23
red 2
yellow 22
```

How can I add the values per the unique strings with bash scripting?

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: You use an associative Array, where the key is the colour and the value is the running sum. In the end, you print the array in a suitable format. You can do this either completely within bash, or in awk, depending on your taste. I personally would do it in awk, but it's really up to you.

Comment: @JeffHolt: Oh, sorry, you are right. My mistake.

Comment: Please add the sample input (i.e. contents of `file.txt`).

Answer (score 2):

First, get out of the [UUoC](https://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat) habit.

```
declare -A totals=()
while read -r color _ count _; do
  totals[$color]=$(( "${totals[$color]:- 0}" + count ))
done < file.txt 
for color in ${!totals[@]}; do echo "$color ${totals[$color]}"; done | sort
```

output:

```
red 25
white 59
yellow 22
```

If it's very big, it would be more efficient in `awk`.

Comment: Suggestions: (1) `declare -Ai totals` (2) `((totals["$color"] += count))`

Answer (score 2):

Sample data file:

```
$ cat file.txt
white stuff 3 more stuff
white stuff 2 more stuff
white stuff 54 more stuff
red stuff 23 more stuff
red stuff 2 more stuff
yellow stuff 22 more stuff
```

One `awk` solution to replace all of the current code **and** generate totals:

```
awk '
    { totals[$1]+=$3}
END { for (i in totals)
          print i,totals[i]
    }
' file.txt

# or as a one-liner

awk '{totals[$1]+=$3} END {for (i in totals) print i,totals[i]}' file.txt
```

This generates:

```
red 25
yellow 22
white 59
```

---

If sorting is required either pipe the output to `sort`, eg:

```
awk '{totals[$1]+=$3} END {for (i in totals) print i,totals[i]}' file.txt | sort
```

Or if using `GNU awk`:

```
awk '
    { totals[$1]+=$3}
END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
      for (i in totals)
          print i,totals[i]
    }
' file.txt
```

Both of these generate:

```
red 25
white 59
yellow 22
```